# Как безопасно исполнить динамическую сборку и выгрузить?

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня такая ситуация. В общем есть wpf приложение на 4.5.2 .net фреймворке, которое генерирует динамически dll и выполняет его. Такая операция происходит с  высокой частотой (скажем до нескольких раз в секунду). При этом особого контроля над генерированной dll нет, в том плане что код в dll может вызывать бесконечную рекурсию, выделять неограниченное количество памяти и тд. На данный момент пока все эти dll грузятся в default app domain (они пока не выгружаются, и я как раз работаю над этим). Моя цель безопасно загружать dll, выгружать а также выполнять (причем так, чтобы код основной программы при этом работал стабильно, процесс не завершался экстренно и тд). Изучив возможности .net я понял что appdomain может частично решить проблему выгрузки dll, но полной безопасности (даже в случае переполнения стэка) этот механиз не предоставляет. более того, это довольно неудобная штука, если необходим маршаллинг между app доменами. И на самом деле там помимо этого много проблем (ну например при маршаллинг в default app domain все равно остается на неопределенное время динамическая библиотека). В общем насколько я понимаю единственный выход это использовать child процесс в котором изолировать dll, и общаться с родительским протоколом через "shared memory"?

Comment: Ну да, судя по описанию, следует использовать второй процесс.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov правда этот вариант не сильно нравится тем что скорее всего у child процесса будет довольно сложная бизнес логика (ведь чтобы на каждый запуск dll не создавать новый процесс надо будет использовать текущий child процесс)  да и протокол обмена данными тоже надо будет придумывать

Comment: Вам придется выбирать между безопасностью/изолированностью (запуск процесса каждый раз) и производительностью (повторное использование процесса). Если не запускать каждый раз новый процесс, то неизвестно в каком состоянии предыдущий запуск его оставил, может там не случилось критической ошибки, но он уже, например, (почти) всю память отожрал.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, именно. Более того, процесс может уйти в бесконечный цикл или например в переполнение и упасть. Безусловно логика с поддержкой одного процесса не будет простой

Comment: 4.5.2 - это что-то с тех времен, когда я был маленький? Почему такой старый фреймворк? А с родительским процессом можно общаться через Named Pipe.

Comment: @aepot проект старый, возможно версия фреймворка будет обновлена. А так, можно и через пайпы общаться. Только использование анонимного пайпа эффективнее чем именованного

Comment: Ну тогда к чему эти вопросы? Вы и так уже неплохо изучили матчасть.

Comment: @aepot было интересно узнать просто существуют ли еще какие нибудь способы средствами .net исполнить и безопасно выгрузить динамическую dll

Comment: Единственный известный мне безопасный способ - использовать отдельный процесс.